# Equivalent of $(@D) in NMake (batch) inference rules

Tags: nmake

I have a bunch of inference rules which I could simplify a lot if I had a way to express *directory of current target*. Normally one would use `$(@D)` for the purpose, but it doesn't seem to work for (batch) inference rules, i.e. the ones ending in `::`:

```
fatal error U1100: macro '$(@D)' is illegal in the context of batch rule [...]
```

Is there an alternative method which is usable in inference rules and would allow me to keep the number of overall rules down and - in particular - not having to repeat myself with something that in another context would become an argument to a function call.

My current workaround is simply to use *non-batch* inference rules. So instead of the batch form:

```
{foo}.c{bar}.obj::
    $(CC) ...
```

I am using the non-batch form, which means it invokes the compiler once per file instead of once per "bunch of files matching the inference rule":

```
{foo}.c{bar}.obj:
    $(CC) ...
```

It also makes the log files quite a lot longer and quite a lot less readable, but it primarily slows down builds.

Comment: btw, I am stuck with NMake for this project, so no need to suggest MSBuild or even GNU make. I *can't* use these, since this is a wrapped `nmake.exe`, wrapped by the WDK build process (`build.exe`). And until we can drop support for certain older versions of Windows, I am stuck with it.

Comment: I've struggled with similar issues in the past, and the sad and _only_ answer I can reasonably give you is this: there is _no way at all_ to do it without resorting to crazy makefile hacks (such as producing sub-makefiles through preprocessing commands and importing them afterwards).